TYPO3 12 filemount entrypoint
While trying to create a new filemount on root level in TYPO3 12, the selectbox for the entry point stays blank. Here are the steps i have taken:

TYPO3 backend: list view
select root in page tree
create new record
choose filemount

It should at least offer /fileadmin as an option to select?


Maybe filesystem permission. Check "Environment -> Directory Status" BE-Modul.

Thanks, i have done this already, the entire installation works without any problems, warnings or errors. The odd thing is, i can create the file mount via the context menu with right click on a folder in the filesystem tree.
